# Function parameter value changing without modification on my behalf

Tags: powershell

I'm a powershell novice and am currently encountering a goofy issue (to me at least) that I'll try my best to explain below.

I'm having issues with what seems to be prior values for a function parameter being "pre-pended" to that same parameter the next time that function is called. That or my two parameters for the function are being combined and something else is occurring that I'm not aware of. Stepping through the ISE debugger has not helped with solving this issue. I'll throw in my code and the text files that I am reading from then explain the issue further below.

```
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
    #Path to file containing weak ACL's before software installation
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)] [string]$BeforeInstallACL = "./Before.txt", 

    #Path to file containing weak ACL's after software installation
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)] [string]$AfterInstallACL = "./After.txt",

    #Folder location of output file
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)] [string]$OutputPath = "./"
)

$latestRegPath = $null

function ReadFromBeforeInstallation ($line, $newRegisteryItem) {
    # Checks if the param (file, dir, or registery key path) exists in $BeforeInstallACL 
    $regItem = $newRegistryItem
    $isPath = CheckIfPath($line)
    Write-Host $line
    $pathFound = $false
    if ($isPath) {
        $content = Get-Content $BeforeInstallACL
        $content | ForEach-Object {
            if ($_.ToString().Trim() -eq $line) {
                $pathFound = $true
                break
            }
       }
       if (!$pathFound) {
           # We have a path that only showed up after installation and want to output this
           $regItem = $line
           WriteToOutput("`r`n{0}`r`n" -f $regItem)
       }
   }
   return $regItem
}

function ReadFromAfterInstallation {
    $content = Get-Content $AfterInstallACL
    $newRegistryItem = $null
    $content | ForEach-Object {
        $_ = $_.Trim()
        if ($_) {
            if ($newRegistryItem) {
                WriteToOutput($_)
            }
            $newRegistryItem = ReadFromBeforeInstallation($_, $newRegistryItem)
        }
        else {
            $newRegistryItem = $null
        }
    }            
}

function WriteToOutput {
    param (
        # Line of a File, Dir or Registery Key from $AfterInstallACl
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=0)]
        [string] $Line
    )
    $Line | Out-File -FilePath $OutputFile -Append
}

function CheckIfPath($line) {
    # Check if the line paramater is a path or not
    $isMatch = $false
    if ($line -match "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE") {
        $isMatch = $true
    }
    return $isMatch
}

#Create the empty output file we're going to use for logging
$OutputFile = Join-Path -Path $OutputPath -ChildPath difference_output.txt
New-Item $OutputFile -type File -force >$null


Get-Date | Out-File -FilePath $OutputFile 
ReadFromAfterInstallation
Get-Date | Out-File -FilePath $OutputFile -Append
```

Here is after.txt

```
Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\DRM
Everyone
SetValue, CreateSubKey, CreateLink, ReadKey, ChangePermissions, TakeOwnership


Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Function Discovery\RegistryStore\Publication\Explorer
Everyone
SetValue, CreateSubKey, ReadKey
BUILTIN\Users
SetValue, CreateSubKey, ReadKey


Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Input\HwkSettings
BUILTIN\Users
SetValue, CreateSubKey, ReadKey
```

and here is before.txt

```
Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Function Discovery\RegistryStore\Publication\Explorer
Everyone
SetValue, CreateSubKey, ReadKey
BUILTIN\Users
SetValue, CreateSubKey, ReadKey


Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Input\HwkSettings
BUILTIN\Users
SetValue, CreateSubKey, ReadKey


Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Input\Locales
BUILTIN\Users
SetValue, CreateSubKey, ReadKey


Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Input\Locales\loc_0039
BUILTIN\Users
SetValue, CreateSubKey, ReadKey
```

The issue is in ReadFromBeforeInstallation() which is called in ReadFromAfterInstallation(). In ReadFromAfterInstallation, I am iterating through the lines of a after.txt, passing them to ReadFromBeforeInstallation and then seeing if the line contains "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE". If so, and that line is not present in before.txt, I want to write the line to my output file.

Sounds simple enough. I'm just trying to find the HKLM registry keys that are in after.txt but not before.txt. What I noticed was that the $line param in ReadFromBeforeInstallation was holding results from past functional calls. A simple Write-Host statement would show lines like the following

```
Everyone Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\DRM
SetValue, CreateSubKey, ReadKey Everyone Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Function Discovery\RegistryStore\Publication\Explorer
```

I never had lines like this in after.txt. Hovering over the $line parameter in ReadFromBeforeInstallation in ISE when the program was running showed that $line was what it was supposed to be too but it once I reached CheckifPath() call it would have an HKEY path appended to it. I'm really stumped what could be going on here. I realize this was a long post, but if anyone could help me out, I would greatly appreciate it.

btw, my powershell version is 5.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the wrong invocation syntax

Change this:

```bsh
ReadFromBeforeInstallation($_, $newRegistryItem)
```

to this:

```bsh
ReadFromBeforeInstallation $_ $newRegistryItem
# or
ReadFromBeforeInstallation -line $_ -newRegisteryItem $newRegistryItem
```

Otherwise, PowerShell will interpret the expression `($_, $newRegistryItem)` as 1 argument and bind that only to the first positional parameter of the function!

The following help topics might be useful in understanding PowerShell's command invocation syntax better:

- [`about_Command_Syntax`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_command_syntax)
- [`about_Parsing`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Parsing)

Comment: Thought I'd try asking here instead of another question (I could make one if you would like), but is there any reason why break exits the whole script instead of just the loop? Using foreach instead of ForEach-Object doesn't solve the issue.  (turns out foreach is an alias for ForEach-Object) Should be able to find out why now

Comment: @ucprogrammer control flow statements don’t work in pipeline iteration. You would need to change to an actual loop —> `foreach ($object in $content) { $object.tostring(); break }`

Comment: Basically what @AdminOfThings said - flow control statements like `break` and `continue` only work inside loop statements - and `ForEach-Object` is not a loop statement, it's a cmdlet that mimics a `foreach` loop

Comment: Thanks guys. I ended up realizing that. Just took me a little bit